# How to set up ray project autoscaling on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ray

I am having real difficulty setting up ray auto-scaling on google cloud compute. I can get it to work on AWS no problem, but I keep running into the following error when running `ray up`:

> googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects?alt=json returned "Service accounts cannot create projects without a parent.">

My project is part of an organization, so I don't understand where this is coming from, or why it would need to create a project in the first place. I have entered my project id in the yaml file like I normally do for AWS.

Thank you very much. I appreciate any help I can get!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message referring to service account, together with the fact that the project already exists, suggests that the googlecloudapiclient used by Ray Autoscaler is authenticated for a service account that doesn't have access to the project.

If this is true, then here's what I believe happens. Typically, when running Ray GCP Autoscaler, it will first check if the project with the given id exists. In your case, this request returns "not found" because there's no project with the given id associated with the service account. Now, because the project did not exist, Ray will automatically try to create one for you. Typically, if we created a new GCP project with a user account (i.e. non-service account), the newly created project would be associated with the user account's default organization. Service accounts, however, must specify a parent organization explicitly when creating a new project. If we look at the [ray.autoscaler.config._create_project](https://github.com/ray-project/ray/blob/36cbde651ac237e0822b17ee1a01d81d0a579e5f/python/ray/autoscaler/gcp/config.py#L341) function, we see that the arguments passed to the `projects.create` method omit the 'parent' argument, which explains why you see the error.

To verify if this is true (and hopefully fix the problem), you could change the account used for authenticating with the googlecloudapiclient. I believe that the credentials used for the googlecloudapiclient requests are the same as used by the Google Cloud SDK, so you should be able to configure the accounts using the [gcloud auth login](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/login) command.

I think the Ray Autoscaler could be improved by either allowing user to explicitly specify the parent organization when creating a new project, or at least by providing a more elaborate error message for this particular case.

I hope this fixes your problem. If it doesn't, and you believe that that it's a problem with the Autoscaler, don't hesitate to open an issue or feature request to the [Ray Issues page](https://github.com/ray-project/ray/issues)!